# Could core Spring framework be used for custom API

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I know basics of Spring but haven't used this widely in projects. So please excuse me if this question is meaningless.

I know we can develop applications, jobs, etc. using Spring but now I am planning to create an internal API in Spring. The artifact(Jar) of which will be used as dependency in other projects. In standalone spring applications, I have initialized Spring beans through contexts and context is loaded by main() class.

But when my API is to be used in other applications, I need to pass bean instances of my service classes(eg: PersistContactService, PersistEmployeeService, etc.) to the third party application. To do this how and when the context to be initialized, so that the internal application can acquire the same bean(instance) initialized with in the context.

When thinking this from another view, it might be meaningless to use spring in such situation itself. Please help to come over this ignorance.

Many Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: You're trying to pass persistence beans to another application?  Do those beans write to the database?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [the Blitline Java SDK](https://github.com/chrylis/blitline-java-client/), which I maintain. The core SDK components don't depend on Spring, but for Spring users, there's a module that sets up a preconfigured environment.

Comment: To put it correct, it is not an independent application. I don't want my another dev team to have the learning curve about the persistence technology used behind in teh app(nosql, sql, etc). They all need to know is business service methods such as persistContact, persistEmployee, etc..

Answer (score 2):

Spring is quite a heavy dependency, so it would depend on the kind of library you're creating. If you know, or it's very likely that Spring would be used in the same project as your library, then having Spring as a dependency doesn't matter. Otherwise it would probably be unnecessarily heavy.